# How to make a flexbox overflowable?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I like to have a div that keeps all it's children in the center (vertical and horizontal). I can easily achieve this by using flexbox. But when my children width get bigger than the parent, overflow: scroll does not work

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ariannargesi/pen/OJzGdBy)

Anybody know why and how can be fixed?

**Update**

My issue has been fixed. BUT, when I add a content to children, the content not showing correctly.

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.children {
  min-width: 1200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="children"><h1>Welcome to my city, California</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use flex-shrink:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the child object is not actually 1200px - it's getting squished down to 500px. However, if you set `min-width: 1200px;` in the child component, it seems to override this and produces the behavior you expect.

Comment: That's because of ```flex-wrap``` behavior

Comment: Thanks' a lot. This really solved my issue. But I'm wondering why I don't need to min-height when height of that children is bigger then 500px!!! Do you know why?

Comment: It looks like the height of the child is only `50px`

Comment: @chase. Yes. It is 50px. But when I change it to something bigger than the parent, overflow work perfectly!

Comment: I added some content to children. content not showing correctly.
@chase